# Mousedown, pointerdown events not working when keep pressing an element

Tags: javascript, html

- I know this is a common question and asked a lot of times but it doesn't seem to work with me i don't know why
- I'm trying to make a counter, function to acting with long press but when i use `mousedown, pointerdown` events and keep pressing on element it doesn't do anything it's acting like `click` event - i'm trying this on Android phone can anyone help me
- What i'm trying to do is increase the counter when user keep press the element
- **Here's an example of my code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Untitled</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css"/>
     <style>
        #ok {
            background: #03fab3;
            padding: 30px;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none; 
            user-select: none;
            touch-action: auto;
        }
     </style>
 </head>
     <body>
        <div id="ok">0</div>
        <script>
            var i = 1,
            ok = document.getElementById("ok")  ;
            ok.addEventListener("pointerdown",  function (e) {
                i++;
                this.innerHTML = i + " " + e.buttons;
            }); 
        </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointerdown`/`mousedown` events do not fire continuously while the button is held. So, you'll need detect two events: when button was pressed and when it was released.

```js
var i = 0,
    el, //this will hold clicked element
    buttons = false,
    lastTimer = 0,
    onPointerEvent = e => buttons = e.buttons; //store pressed buttons in a variable

ok.addEventListener("pointerdown",  function (e)
{
  el = e.target;
  onPointerEvent(e);
  i = 0; //reset counter
  counter(); //start the counter
}, true);

window.addEventListener("pointerup",  onPointerEvent); //non-touch devices
window.addEventListener("pointercancel",  onPointerEvent); //touch devices


function counter(timer)
{
  if (!buttons) //exit loop when button released
    return;

  if (timer >= lastTimer + 10) //update counter every 10ms
  {
    lastTimer = timer;
    el.textContent = ++i + " " + buttons;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(counter); //create loop
}
```

```css
#ok > *{
    background: #03fab3;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none;
    touch-action: auto;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ok">
  <div>0</div>
  <div>0</div>
  <div>0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a problem with this function when i press and move the pointer over the element and take up the pointer it's will keep working and won't stop after i remove the pointer from this element

Comment: @MahmoudY3c Are you sure? It works fine in my browser...it stops even if I move cursor away from browser

Comment: You probably need to tie your pointerup to pointerleave and pointerexit as well, I think. Common thing people forget: but if you click on the page, move the mouse out and release, you will never detect the pointerup event on page, locking you into pointermove.

Comment: Hens the `pointerup` event listener is registered on `window` object, it's supposed to fire regardless of where the cursor is? At least it does so in chromium-based browsers I've tested so far.

Comment: No it's won't stop here is a video https://drive.google.com/file/d/16dtLtNH8Oxik0Kga5DPk6SGgaw2W76IW/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: That is strange behavior on touch devices. Adding `window.addEventListener("pointercancel",  onPointerEvent);` or changing in css `touch-action` to `none`  seems to work

Comment: Thank you it's working now update your answer and set `touch-action` to `none` i also done a simple function depending on the first answer ```var i = 0, timer;
ok.addEventListener("pointerup", function(e){
 i = 0;
 clearInterval(timer);
}, true);
ok.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(e) {
 _this = this
  timer = setInterval(function () {
    _this.textContent = ++i + " " + e.buttons;
  }, 100);
});``` thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mousedown simply checks whether the click event started. Until you se "mouseup" event, you need to create a "Setinterval" and increase your variable depending on time.

So looking "mousedown" event is just acts like "click" event of the browser without additional controls.

Comment: That's helpful thank you it was going to be better if you just provided an example