# Pointerup event not triggered after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, user-interaction

I have a web interface with a set of buttons that must be pressed for some time to work. The job of the buttons is to send a signal if they've been pressed for more than a second and send the opposite value of the signal after that.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" name='button1' type="button">Butt. A</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" name='button2'>Butt. 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS looks a bit like this.

```
$("button").on("pointerdown", handlePointerDown);
$("button").on("pointerup", handlePointerUp);

function handlePointerDown(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Handle Pointer Down triggered");
    //something something something
}

function handlePointerUp(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Handle Pointer Up triggered");
    //something something something
}
```

My issue here is that when I'm testing the app for mobile (either on a real phone or in the mobile mode of Chrome console), I've noticed that, because of the long press, sometimes the user scrolls slightly on the screen (think about a user which presses the button, and because they have to hold it, they move their finger barely a couple of millimeters on the screen, enough to trigger the scroll). This scroll apparently disables/interrupts the natural sequence of events (the user presses the button -> `handlePointerDown` is triggered; the user releases a button -> `handlePointerUp` is triggered), hence `handlePointerUp` is not called.

Can I fix it without having the page "kidnapping" my `pointerup` event?

Comment: You can try adding a pointercancel event as shown in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71901918/535480), not sure if you will have to detect pointerup/pointercancel on the window instead of the button.

Comment: @James it works on the button element itself: https://jsfiddle.net/1fymaws5/ (very hard to use jsfiddle on mobile)

Comment: @James but I don't want to cancel the pointer up event, nor I want to handle the pointer up event as a pointer cancel one.

Comment: Pointercancel reacts to a pointer event being cancelled.  It does not cancel a pointer event.

Comment: @James based on my tests, when I press a button, move the finger slightly and raise the finger from the screen, the pointerup event is not triggered

Comment: The idea is that the pointercancel event will handle that scenario.

Comment: But I want to make the page a bit resilient to that small movement, it doesn't "finish" the click